# How to draw 1/3 circle on Xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm designing a layout as below with `Xamarin Forms`.

[image: hatf_circle]

1) How do we draw such a layout?

and 2) How do we draw 1/3 circle?

Please help me!

**Reference**: [Draw Circle in Xamarin form](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91915/draw-circle-in-xamarin-form)

Comment: you can use [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) for this, you can get started [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/)

Comment: also you can see this awesome guy, he use skiasharp [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUk5Jtvmx8Q&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: That is an image, though.

Comment: Having a look at [this article by using Custom renderer](https://www.devprotocol.com/draw-a-circle-with-a-xamarin-forms-custom-renderer/) ,maybe helpful to find the woraround.

Comment: @Huu Bao Nguyen Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to set the CornerRadius of bottom-left and bottom-right. You can use the **[Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction)** .

in Forms ,create a subclass of **BoxView**

```
public class MyBoxView:BoxView
{

}
```

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

  <local:MyBoxView BackgroundColor = "Red"  WidthRequest="800" HeightRequest="200"  />

</StackLayout>
```

#### in iOS

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using CoreGraphics;
using CoreAnimation;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyBoxView),typeof(MyViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
    {
        public override void LayoutSublayersOfLayer(CALayer layer)
        {
            base.LayoutSublayersOfLayer(layer);


            var path = UIBezierPath.FromRoundedRect(this.Bounds, UIRectCorner.BottomRight | UIRectCorner.BottomLeft, new CGSize(1000, 1000));  //set CornerRadius  here !!
            var mask = new CAShapeLayer();
            mask.Path = path.CGPath;

            this.Layer.Mask = mask;
        }      
    }
}
```

#### in Android

creat a xml file in the folder **Resource->drawable** boxview_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape
      android:shape="rectangle">
      <solid
        android:color="#ffffff" />
      <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="1000dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="1000dp" />

    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

```
using Android.Support.V4.Content.Res;
using xxx;
using App11.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(MyBoxView),typeof(MyViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyViewRenderer : BoxRenderer
 {
   public MyAndriodEntry(Context context):base(context)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.boxview_style);
        }

    }
  }
}
```